# Finding the position in a list of the closest value to a given number

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of values, not necessarily sorted, for example

```
list=[1.1,0.7,1.8,2.,1.65]
```

and I want to find the position in the list of the closest value to a given number, for example `a=1.4`. It does not matter whether the value in the list is larger or smaller than the given value. Of course, one way to do it is with a `for` loop

```
import numpy as np
d=100.
i=0
for s in list:
    if np.abs(s-a)<d:
        pos=i
        d=np.abs(s-a)   
    i+=1
print pos
```

but in python there must be a much better way. How can I do it more synthetically ?
What if the values are instead sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert this to a numpy array and calculate the index of the minimum absolute difference between the items and `target`, like:

```
def min_diff_pos(array_like, target):
    return np.abs(np.array(array_like)-target).argmin()
```

For example:

```
>>> min_diff_pos([1.1,0.7,1.8,2.,1.65], 1.1)
0
>>> min_diff_pos([1.1,0.7,1.8,2.,1.65], 1.8)
2
>>> min_diff_pos([1.1,0.7,1.8,2.,1.65], 1.7)
4
>>> min_diff_pos([1.1,0.7,1.8,2.,1.65], 1.79)
2
```

If the values are sorted, we can use a binary search algorithm, and then look at the two items that are near the insertion point. In that case it is the closest of these two. This makes a lookup *O(log n)* instead of *O(n)*:

```
def min_diff_pos_sorted(sorted_array, target):
    idx = np.searchsorted(sorted_array, target)
    idx1 = max(0, idx-1)
    return np.abs(np.array(sorted_array[idx1:idx+1])-target).argmin() + idx1
```

For example:

```
>>> data = np.array([0.7, 1.1, 1.65, 1.8, 2.0])
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 0.7)
0
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 0.8)
0
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 0.9)
0
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 1.0)
1
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 1.1)
1
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 1.2)
1
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 1.3)
1
>>> min_diff_pos_sorted(data, 1.4)
2
```

Comment: Small nitpick: "`np.array(some_iterable)`" suggests that `np.array` can digest general iterables which is not the case. You'd have to use something like `np.fromiter` for that.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: thanks. I will change the parameter to `array_like`, since the mandatory `dtype` could result in rounding errors, overflow, etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

a pretty straitforward solution without numpy or other third party tools:

```
values = [1.1, 0.7, 1.8, 2., 1.65]

def get_min_pos(values, referencevalue):
    d = [(referencevalue - x)**2 for x in values]
    return d.index(min(d))
```

a first test:

```
testvalues = values
for value in testvalues:
    expected_pos = values.index(value)
    pos = get_min_pos(values=values, referencevalue=value)
    assert pos == expected_pos

# list of testvalue and expected indox pos for the value
testvalues = [(1.0, 0), (0.8, 1), (0.9, 0), (0.89, 1), ]
for value, expected_pos in testvalues:
    value = get_min_pos(values=values, referencevalue=value)
    assert value == expected_pos
```

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be quicker, with very long lists, to use: get_min_pos = lambda L,ref: min([((ref-x)**2,i) for i,x in enumerate(L)])[1]

Comment: why should it be quicker? So far i see your code checks all the list elements?